# Aumentar ratio de pantalla para Samsung S8 y LG G6 en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Con la salida de nuevos terminales más apaisados como es el LG G6 y el Samsung S8, las apps se visualizan con una franja negra en la parte superior y la inferior, como se puede ajustar que la app se expande en su totalidad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede especificar el ratio soportado para la App en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

Con la propiedad `android.max_aspect` se puede asignar el valor máximo que la App mantendrá su aspecto, adaptandose a el.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect"
    android:value="ratio_float"/>
```

Para pantallas con formato `19:6` su valor es `1.86` y para que la app se pueda expandir a otro ratio.

```
<application>
...
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
...
</aplication>
```

Extraido de [Blog oficial de dev Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html)

Comment: Interesante, es algo que desconocía! ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏